# Old cartoon where kid gets super strength from boomerang in his shirt

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm looking for the name of an old cartoon that I watched as a kid where a kid gets super strength when a boomerang gets in his shirt (behind his back). I think the boomerang kid was a side character, not a main one.

Comment: Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can [edit] in any more details, like when you saw it, etc.

Comment: Marine Boy used to use a boomerang style weapon?

Comment: Wikipedia: Marine Boy also carries a weapon: a boomerang made of a hardened alloy. The alloy can cut through many materials and the nimble Marine Boy has even used it to deflect bullets (ep. 24). It folds on a spring so it can be carried in a holster on his left arm. When unfolded and thrown it can generate a powerful electric shock, which has proved to be so disruptive to some electrical systems, it has blown up entire submarines (ep. 14, 16, 28).

Comment: Not [Bananaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bananaman_(TV_series))? - He eats bananas rather than getting them in his shirt.